# What would the @ do on a coffeescript Class Name

Tags: class, coffeescript

So im fairly new to coffee-script having to learn it fairly quick for a new job.  What would the differences be between the following code:

```
class Person
```

versus

```
class @Person
```

If I use the following

```
bob = new Person()
```

how would the results differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the full JavaScript that `class C` and `class @C` produce, things should be clearer. `class C` becomes (with some cleanup):

```
(function() {
  var C = (function() {
    function C() {}
    return C;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

So the `C` "class" is actually a local variable in a self-invoking function (SIF) wrapper. This wrapper is part of how CoffeeScript handles [scoping](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.

If we look at `class @C`, we'll see almost the same thing:

```
(function() {
  this.C = (function() {
    function C() {}
    return C;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

The difference is `var C` (local variable) versus `this.C` (property on whatever `this` is).

So what is `this` inside the SIF? `this` inside will be whatever it is outside:

```
(function() { ... }).call(this)
// -----------------------^^^^
```

because [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is used to invoke the SIF. What will `this` be outside the SIF? In a browser, it will be `window` so `class @C` is equivalent to `class window.C` and properties of `window` are globally visible; thus `class @C` will make `C` globally visible in a browser environment whereas a simple `class C` will only be visible in the file where it is defined.

A more common approach (at least in the code I've worked with) is to have a globally visible application-specific namespace:

```
// Somewhere before anything else happens...
window.whatever_the_app_is_called = { };
```

and then you put your classes somewhere in that namespace:

```
class whatever_the_app_is_called.C
    #...
```

If you're using Require.js or node.js then they have their own namespacing patterns that you'd use.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the in depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

`@` is for `this` so `class @Person` is compiled to `this.Person =`  ...

You can check what the compiled JS looks like at [coffeescript.org/#try](https://coffeescript.org/#try).